# odeke-em/drive installation

Tags: drive, google-drive, golang

The installation of `drive` wasn't as straightforward as I thought. I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#installing). `Go` is now working I think.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ go version
go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "$HOME/go".
For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

Then I executed the following command as instructed. For some reason I had to `sudo` the command.

```
go get -u github.com/odeke-em/drive/cmd/drive
```

It took some time and showed no output when done. Not sure if that's supposed to happen. Anyway, I headed to the initialization of `drive` with following output.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mkdir drive && cd drive
user@ubuntu:~/drive$ drive init
Command 'drive' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install drive
```

Does someone have any clue what I might be doing wrong? The instructions seem so simple and yet I manage to mess up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was resolved by installing using the [Platform Packages](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/blob/master/platform_packages.md)

The process for Debian, or Debian based distros (Eg: Ubuntu)

Pre-requisites:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common dirmngr
```

Note: The apt-key command is no longer required on apt 1.1 systems. It's safe to ignore any error presented.

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7086E9CC7EC3233B
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drive
```